# Giving window.open popup a title

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to give the popup window in window.open a title. However i'm failing to do so. Any help or suggestions please?

```
function view() {
    window.open(url,"_self");           
}
```

Comment: Once you open the window, you will lose control of it because you have `_self`. What is the `url`? Is it your domain?

Comment: @AdamAzad yes it's my domain

Comment: Add the `<title>` to the page, then. Simple!

Answer (score 1):

You can change the title after opening the window.

```
var myWindow = window.open("", "", "width=200, height=100");
myWindow.document.writeln('<html><head><title>Your new title here</title></head>');
```

Comment: the one that works!